SwiftUI and FirestoreQuery property wrapper - Pagination?
I'm new to using the property wrapper for FirestoreQuery and I'm confused how to handle pagination.
@FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "users") private var users: [Users]

Would this simply respond with all users? I know you can limit it but how would you do limit and then paginate results?
